# How to Use three contions in two columns in excell if both have same +ve sign true & if bot have -ve sign false,no condtion for mixed signs

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, sign

How to Use three contions in two columns in excell if both have same +ve sign true & if bot have -ve sign false,no condtion for mixed signs

I have taken two columns that contains +ve & -ve values.
The result I need in third column with conditions
1.If both values in two columns have +ve (positive) sign represent it as TRUE.
2.If both values in two columns have -ve(negative) sign represent it as False.
3.If both have mixed signs represent don't represent it as either TRUE OR FALSE. Just leave it blank in column three.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=IF(AND(A1>0,B1>0),TRUE,IF(AND(A1<0,B1<0),FALSE,""))
```

or

```
=IF(SIGN(A1)=SIGN(B1),IF(SIGN(A1)=1,TRUE,FALSE),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

[image]

Comment: you are ALMOST answering at the speed of Scott Craner.  Nice job answering with photo in under 7 minutes!

Comment: @ForwardEd - Thank you but I guess its because I'm getting bored with no work at the moment.

Comment: Scott says something similar...something to do while waiting on code to compile/run